# Java in browser... opening a socket

Tags: java, sockets, browser

I don't mind presenting the user with permission dialogs... What's involved in opening a listening socket on a web page?

Comment: I doubt that's possible. That would be a serious security leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you use a signed applet. The user has to accept the applet and after that you can do about anything you can do with a standalone Java application.

Answer (score 1):

The browser sandbox allows you to open a socket back to the originating server.  That should be enough.

The main alternatives for connecting sockets to other address entail using a signed applet, a browser plugin / addon, or (possibly) an ActiveX control.  All of these alternatives require the user to take active steps to "accept" or install stuff, and all of them are a potential security risk for the user ... whether or not you are one of the good guys who don't push malware at people.